# How do i solve this"... .so: undefined reference to '..."

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, catkin, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have gone through the internet for hours for similar cases to mine but I've tried all solutions and hasn't got my code working. I'm using a library called "vdo_slam" which has been built and can be found in /usr/local/include/vdo_slam. In my project CMakeList.txt I can find_package(vdo_slam REQUIRED) with no error. The only problem I have is at the end of "catkin_build" I get several of these "undefined reference to ...." as shown below. I have tried several solutions as listed below. All these undefined references are declared and defined inside the "vdo_slam" package. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Known solutions I have taken:

> 1. I looked for classes and functions mentioned in the errors and see if there are pure virtual destructors as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065154/undefined-reference-to-vtable) but they are all defined solidly.

> 2. I have tried to debug with "readelf" command as shown below referring to [this](https://www.uppmax.uu.se/support/faq/software-faq/undefined-reference-when-compiling-program--what-to-do/). But i don't have the "libvdo_slam.so" which actually includes these functions in the error. I suppose i need to have "libvdo_slam.so" when i  run this "readelf" command right? How can i add that?

Error code from "catkin_build":

```
/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for VDO_SLAM::Visualizer2D'
/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined reference to `vtable for VDO_SLAM::Visualizer2D'
/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined reference to `vtable for VDO_SLAM::SceneObject'
/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined reference to `VDO_SLAM::BoundingBox::BoundingBox(double, double, double, double)'
/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined reference to `VDO_SLAM::Scene::Scene()'
/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined reference to `VDO_SLAM::Visualizer2D::spinOnce(std::shared_ptr<VDO_SLAM::Scene>&)'
/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined reference to `VDO_SLAM::Scene::add_scene_object(std::shared_ptr<VDO_SLAM::SceneObject>&)'
/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so: undefined reference to `VDO_SLAM::Visualizer2D::Visualizer2D(std::shared_ptr<VDO_SLAM::VisualizerParams>&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
my_realtime_vdo_slam/CMakeFiles/ros_vdoslam_node.dir/build.make:226: recipe for target '/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/my_realtime_vdo_slam/ros_vdoslam_node' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/my_realtime_vdo_slam/ros_vdoslam_node] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6593: recipe for target 'my_realtime_vdo_slam/CMakeFiles/ros_vdoslam_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [my_realtime_vdo_slam/CMakeFiles/ros_vdoslam_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j12 -l12" failed
```

$ readelf --dynamic /home/tranks/testing_ws/devel/lib/libmy_realtime_vdo_slam.so
[Here](https://imgur.com/a/6tYHNqy)

This is my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(my_realtime_vdo_slam)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  flow_net
  geometry_msgs
  image_transport
  mask_rcnn
  message_generation
  midas_ros
  mono_depth_2
  nav_msgs
  python_service_starter
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  tf
  tf2
  tf2_geometry_msgs
  tf2_ros
  tf2_sensor_msgs
  vision_msgs
  visualization_msgs
  nodelet
  message_filters
)

find_package(OpenCV)
find_package(vdo_slam REQUIRED)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
add_message_files(
   FILES
   VdoSlamScene.msg
   VdoSlamMap.msg
   VdoSceneObject.msg
   VdoInput.msg
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES 
    actionlib_msgs 
    geometry_msgs 
    std_msgs 
    sensor_msgs 
    mask_rcnn 
    vision_msgs
)


set(PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRS
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${vdo_slam_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  )

include_directories(
  ${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)  


catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS ${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME} 
  CATKIN_DEPENDS 
    roscpp
    image_transport 
    python_service_starter 
    std_msgs 
    tf 
    tf2 
    tf2_geometry_msgs 
    tf2_ros 
    tf2_sensor_msgs 
    nav_msgs 
    sensor_msgs 
    geometry_msgs 
    cv_bridge 
    flow_net 
    mask_rcnn 
    mono_depth_2 
    midas_ros 
    message_runtime 
    nodelet
    message_filters
  # DEPENDS system_lib
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED 
  src/RosVdoSlam.cpp
  src/utils/RosUtils.cpp
  src/visualizer/RosVisualizer.cpp
    src/visualizer/RosAsyncManager.cpp
  src/tracking/HungarianSolver.cpp
    src/tracking/SemanticTracker.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
        ${OpenCV_LIBS}
        ${vdo_slam_LIBRARIES}
)
#if(catkin_EXPORTED_LIBRARIES)
#  add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}
#         ${catkin_EXPORTED_LIBRARIES}
#         ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
#         ${OpenCV_LIBS}
 #     ${vdo_slam_LIB_DIRS})
# endif()

# target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} SYSTEM PUBLIC
#     ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
#     ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
#     ${vdo_slam_INCLUDE_DIRS}
#     $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
#     $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
# )


add_executable(ros_vdoslam_node 
  src/ros_vdoslam_node.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(ros_vdoslam_node 
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}
  ${vdo_slam_LIBRARIES}
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  )

if(catkin_EXPORTED_LIBRARIES)
  add_dependencies(ros_vdoslam_node
          ${catkin_EXPORTED_LIBRARIES}
          ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
          ${OpenCV_LIBS}
      ${vdo_slam_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377170/how-do-i-solve-this%22...-.so:-undefined-reference-to-%27...%22/) by [TK27](https://answers.ros.org/users/72639/tk27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-04-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-04-27**:\

> [...] I have gone through the internet for hours for similar cases to mine but I've tried all solutions and hasn't got my code working

What similar cases, what solutions, and what were the results? This information will help others not suggest things that you've already attempted. Could you please update your question with this information?

**Comment by [TK27](https://answers.ros.org/users/72639/tk27/) on 2021-04-28**:
Yes Sorry i put it up in a rush. I have added what I have tried in the post. Please let me know if i need to add anything else. Thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-28**:\

> target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
> >         ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
> ${OpenCV_LIBS}
> >         ${vdo_slam_LIB_DIRS}
> # /home/tranks/testing_ws/src/VDO_SLAM/build/libvdo_slam.so
> )

I'm not saying it will solve your problem, but you're not linking correctly here.

`target_link_libraries(..)` takes either a CMake target, or a (list of) absolute paths to libraries.

You're passing it a directory (if the naming of `vdo_slam_LIB_DIRS` is correct).

**Comment by [TK27](https://answers.ros.org/users/72639/tk27/) on 2021-04-28**:
@gvdhoorn Yes it should be `${vdo_slam_LIBRARIES}` instead. I found that my current library is not linked to that libvdo_slam.so when I ran the `$ldd` or `$readelf` on the my library so file. Shouldn't it be linked since I already did `target_link_libraries(... vdo_slam_LIBRARIES ...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67294775/how-do-i-solve-this-so-undefined-reference-to/67352140#67352140):

> Eureka! I found a solution although it's not an ideal one. As mentioned in the question, I noticed that `libvdo_slam.so` was not listed as a shared library when running `$ readelf <on_my_library.so>`. So I manually added `-lvdo_slam` in the CMakeList.txt so it looks like:
>
> ```
> target_link_libraries(ros_vdoslam_node  
>   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}  
> >       ${OpenCV_LIBS}    
>   ${PROJECT_NAME}  
> >       -lvdo_slam  
> >       )  `
> > 
> > Moreover, since "vdo_slam" also uses a modified "g2o" library, the same procedure had to be done in the VDO_SLAM library's CMakeList.txt(which is adding `-lvdo_slam_g2o` in a similar place).
> > 
> > Although it builds successfully now, I still wonder why this happened. From my understanding, `-lvdo_slam` is the same as `${vdo_slam_LIBS}`, and the latter should be valid after using `find_package(vdo_slam REQUIRED)`
> ```

---

Originally posted by [TK27](https://answers.ros.org/users/72639/tk27/) with karma: 16 on 2021-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-02**:
Please do not post link-only answers. This is not accepted on Stack Overflow, neither here on ROS Answers.

I've quoted your StackOverflow answer in your answer here.

**Comment by [TK27](https://answers.ros.org/users/72639/tk27/) on 2021-05-02**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks for the notice. Cheers